# How to set the output of python Pandas' value_counts() to a datatype other than int64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am utilizing the value count function to analyze the data within a large pandas dataframe (n = 2483903973). The basic design of my df is:

```
df = {'Value': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'Class': pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 1)}


Value    int32
Class      int8
dtype: object
```

I have repeating values and repeating classes. I am then running the following code so as to count the number of occurrences for each Value:Class combination.

```
df = df.value_counts().rename_axis(['Value','Class']).reset_index(name='counts')

   Value  Class  Counts
0  0      1      2
1  1      1      1
2  1      2      1


Value     int64
Class      int64
Counts    int64
dtype: object
```

My issue is that the output of value_counts() is a dtype of int64, which is taking up way too much memory for what I need. I am looking for a way to set the dtype of the output to something smaller, honestly like int16 would work. I looked at the method docs, but didn't see a parameter to pass. ANy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

#It may not work for big integers

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'Class': pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 1])})
df = df.value_counts().rename_axis(['Value','Class']).reset_index(name='counts').astype('int16')

print(df)

  Value  Class  counts
0      0      1       2
1      1      1       1
2      1      2       1
```

---

```
print(df.dtypes)

Value     int16
Class     int16
counts    int16
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! I was thinking it was a parameter I had to pass, but this worked just fine